# I got a token from AAD using Msal, but can't get the user profile using the token acquired. How to validate the token simply on Node backend?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication

I used the following configuration for requesting the token from AAD.

The app.module.ts file:

```
MsalModule.forRoot({
            clientID: 'CLIENT_ID',
            authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID",
            validateAuthority: true,
            cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
            postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/authorize/signin',
            navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
            popUp: true,
            consentScopes: ['user.read', 'https://graph.microsoft.com']
        }
```

It returns the msal.idtoken, accesstoken, and some more msal key value pairs.
Now following code is used to get the profile of the user by pasting the acquired MSAL_IDTOKEN.

```
const request = require('request');
const tok = 'MSAL_IDTOKEN HERE';
request.get({ url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + tok, "Content-type": "application/json" } }, function (err, response, body) {

    if (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
    }
    else
        console.log(response.body);
})
```

Now after running the app on Node, it used to return the profile of the user, as found after decoding the token, but now it does not.

Comment: have you assign the permission on azure portal?

Comment: Yes, it is added.

Comment: @AniketSingh Can u help me to get "const tok = 'MSAL_IDTOKEN HERE';" using msal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you have the right config on the Portal.

If you are using MSAL.js, given some code like this:

```
    this.app = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(

        this.applicationConfig.clientID,

        `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${AzureADName}/`,

        () => {

            // callback for login redirect

        },

        {

            redirectUri

        }

    );
```

You would then call this to get user information:

```
this.app.getUser();
```

or

```
this.app.getAccount();
```

You would have to provide version information to be sure, as the API was changed.

Answer (score 1):

Get User Profile only works for `msal": "^0.2.4"` and not for the current version 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your are trying to read user profile from your access token.

To do that you need to assign `profile` dedicated permission on azure portal.

See the screen shot below:

[image]

> **Note:**  After assigning permission you can check your token on [`https://jwt.io/`](https://jwt.io/) whether it contains required permission.

**Token Claim:**

[image]

**Read User data:**

[image]

**Code Snippet:**

**Token Class:**

```cs
 public class AccessTokenClass
        {
            public string token_type { get; set; }
            public string expires_in { get; set; }
            public string resource { get; set; }
            public string scope { get; set; }
            public string access_token { get; set; }
            public string refresh_token { get; set; }

        }
```

**Token Method:**

```cs
private async Task<string> GetTokenByROPCFormat()
        {

            string tokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenantIdOrName/oauth2/token";

            var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);

            tokenRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["grant_type"] = "password",
                ["client_id"] = "b603c7be-a866--e6921e61f925",
                ["client_secret"] = "Vxf1SluKbgu4PF0Nf3wE5oG",
                ["resource"] = "https://graph.microsoft.com",
                ["username"] = "kironmemb@MyTenant.onmicrosoft.com",
                ["password"] = "@Mypassword"

            });

            dynamic json;
            dynamic results;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            var tokenResponse = await client.SendAsync(tokenRequest);

            json = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenClass>(json);
            Console.WriteLine("Your Refresh Token=>{0}", results.refresh_token);



            //  New Block For Accessing Data from API
            HttpClient newClient = new HttpClient();

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me");

            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", results.access_token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await newClient.SendAsync(request);

            string output = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return output;




        }
```

Comment: Yes, the profile permission is added in the portal. It still does not returns the profile. FYI, when I paste the token in jwt.ms, it decodes and gives the profile almost like I need.

Comment: @AniketSingh have you decoded your token on jwt? does it contain that permission?

Comment: "aud": "CLIENT_ID",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/v2.0",
  "iat": ,
  "nbf": ,
  "exp": 1559207087,
  "aio": "",
  "name": "Aniket Singh",
  "nonce": "",
  "oid": "",
  "preferred_username": "Aniket@ssrx.com",
  "sub": "",
  "tid": "",
  "uti": "",
  "ver": "2.0"

Comment: This is the JSON that I received. I have removed and aliased the values purposefully.

Comment: Can you let me know how you're generating the token? The URL and rest? Thank you !

Comment: @AniketSingh I have updated the answer. Please consider `C#` I am not expert on node.js. But given the proper [node.js example here](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback) also can [see](https://medium.com/swlh/a-practical-guide-for-jwt-authentication-using-nodejs-and-express-d48369e7e6d4)