# Azure AD with msal-node: How to get user profile?

Tags: express, azure-ad-msal, react-aad-msal, msal-react

I have a nodejs/expressjs application that uses `@azure/msal-node` [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-node) for user-login. For this, I followed the [official Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal).

User login works like a charm.

But now I have to access the user's profile, and most important, the user's name. I tried many solutions, but nothing works.

For example, in `server.js`, I tried `this.app.getUser();` as well as `this.app.getAccount();`
as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56374240/i-got-a-token-from-aad-using-msal-but-cant-get-the-user-profile-using-the-toke). But this does not work and in the Thread I linked here, someone says it only works with version "^0.2.4". Tried this, but npm could not find this version.

And as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63072668/how-to-get-user-profile-details-using-azure-ad) answer, I also set `family_name` and `general_name` in Azure AD for my application, but I do not know how to get the information from the Token. Because in Chrome Developer Tools, there is no Token sent that contains these information.

Here is what I have so far:

```
// server.js
const path = require('path');

const express = require("express");
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');

const SERVER_PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000; 
const REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:3000"; 

const config = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "xyz",
        authority: "xyz",
        clientSecret: "xyz"
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback(loglevel, message, containsPii) {
                console.log(message);
            },
            piiLoggingEnabled: false,
            logLevel: msal.LogLevel.Verbose,
        }
    }
};

// Create msal application object
const pca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(config);

// Create Express App and Routes
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './build')));

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    const authCodeUrlParameters = {
        scopes: ["user.read"],
        redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI,
    };

    // get url to sign user in and consent to scopes needed for application
    pca.getAuthCodeUrl(authCodeUrlParameters).then((response) => {
        console.log("my response: ", response);
        // Here I tried pca.getUser(); and pca.getAccount();
        res.redirect(response);
    }).catch((error) => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));
});

app.listen(SERVER_PORT, () => console.log(`Msal Node Auth Code Sample app listening on port ${SERVER_PORT}!`))
```

Since I works with `express.js` and React as frontend: Should I better user [msal-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-react)? I wanted to avoid this because this is not officially supported by Microsoft.